# Change ckeditor language using Asp.net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, ckeditor, view

I am working on a asp.net core 1.1 web application. In one of the create views i need to use ckeditor.
i can use ckeditor well but i want to change default language.
how can i change language in ckeditor? and Where should I make changes?

my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="BookDescription" class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"></textarea>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');

            </script>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hamid, you can specify default language in your view, like this -

`CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {language: 'en'});`

Or you can add to CKEditor config.js file like this

`config.language = 'en';`

Please, check more information here https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_uilanguage